# Electron - Prevent Window close from Render process

Tags: electron

I wanted to prevent my electron app from closing so I can trigger some code (like saving data) before the end of my application from the render process.

Since e.PreventDefault() didn't worked for me (from both render and main process) I had to found another way. I wanted to share it if someone had the same problem than me.

You can find my answer below :)

Comment: It's `preventDefault()` not `PreventDefault()` (lowercase 'p'). Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. From the render process. You can use `window.onbeforeunload` to prevent the window from closing by returning any value (false, true or any string).

Here is just created a boolean called "**CanCloseWindow**" that will return something if false inside the **window.onbeforeunload** function to prevent my window from closing.

Electron ***remote.getCurrentWindow()*** will return the current BrowserWindow object. I can use that to get the **.on('close')** event.

If "**CanCloseWindow**" is false. I will launch a promise.allSettled with all the tasks I want to run before my application is closing. I can also launch synchrone tasks after if I wanted to.

Once finished. I can set the boolean "**CanCloseWindow**" to true, and ask the application to try to close it's windows again with **app.quit()**

All this code will be executed again, but since **CanCloseWindow** is true, my tasks won't run, and my application will close.

```js
var CanCloseWindow = false; 
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    if(CanCloseWindow === false) {return false} 
}
    
remote.getCurrentWindow().on('close', ()=>{
    if(CanCloseWindow === false){
        var editorconfig = EditorConfig.getInstance();
        Promise.allSettled([
            editorconfig.set('.BrowserWindow.x', CurrentWindow.getPosition()[0]),
            editorconfig.set('.BrowserWindow.y', CurrentWindow.getPosition()[1]),
            editorconfig.set('.BrowserWindow.width', CurrentWindow.getSize()[0]),
            editorconfig.set('.BrowserWindow.height', CurrentWindow.getSize()[1]),
            editorconfig.set('.BrowserWindow.fullscreen', CurrentWindow.isFullScreen())
        ])
        .then((results)=>{
            CanCloseWindow = true;
            remote.app.quit();
        })
    }
})
```